Error While Loading APIs on WSO APIM 4.2.0
APIs are not loading on wso2 apim publisher/devportal while login and give some errors below. Third-party Postgres DB is configured for APIM. What could be the reason for that?
[2024-04-16 15:52:36,388] ERROR - JDBCAuthorizationManager Error occurred while accessing Java Security Manager Privilege Block


[2024-04-16 15:52:36,393] ERROR - DefaultRealm nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:402) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:318) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:136) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:276) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.(DefaultRealmService.java:102) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.(DefaultRealmService.java:115) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:80) ~[?:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61) ~[?:?]
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:842) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569) ~[?:?]
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:834) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:791) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1013) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:365) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:598) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:462) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$1.run(ModuleContainer.java:1820) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$2$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:150) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1813) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1770) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1735) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1661) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[?:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:356) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
... 25 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Error occurred while accessing Java Security Manager Privilege Block
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager.callSecure(JDBCAuthorizationManager.java:1530) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager.populatePermissionTreeFromDB(JDBCAuthorizationManager.java:1388) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager.(JDBCAuthorizationManager.java:175) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[?:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:356) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
... 25 more
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:573) ~[?:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager.callSecure(JDBCAuthorizationManager.java:1515) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager.populatePermissionTreeFromDB(JDBCAuthorizationManager.java:1388) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager.(JDBCAuthorizationManager.java:175) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[?:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:356) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager$2.run(JDBCAuthorizationManager.java:1518) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569) ~[?:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager.callSecure(JDBCAuthorizationManager.java:1515) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager.populatePermissionTreeFromDB(JDBCAuthorizationManager.java:1388) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager.(JDBCAuthorizationManager.java:175) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[?:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:356) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.contains(java.lang.CharSequence)" because "name" is null
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.TreeNode.modify(TreeNode.java:309) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.TreeNode.authorizeRole(TreeNode.java:151) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.PermissionTree.authorizeRoleInTree(PermissionTree.java:170) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.PermissionTree.updatePermissionTreeFromDB(PermissionTree.java:1140) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager.populatePermissionTreeFromDB(JDBCAuthorizationManager.java:1391) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager$2.run(JDBCAuthorizationManager.java:1518) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569) ~[?:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager.callSecure(JDBCAuthorizationManager.java:1515) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager.populatePermissionTreeFromDB(JDBCAuthorizationManager.java:1388) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager.(JDBCAuthorizationManager.java:175) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[?:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:356) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
... 25 more
[2024-04-16 15:52:36,394] ERROR - Activator Cannot start User Manager Core bundle
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Cannot initialize the realm.
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:286) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.(DefaultRealmService.java:102) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.(DefaultRealmService.java:115) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:80) ~[?:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61) ~[?:?]
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:842) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569) ~[?:?]
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:834) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:791) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1013) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:365) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:598) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:462) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$1.run(ModuleContainer.java:1820) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$2$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:150) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1813) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1770) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1735) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1661) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:323) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:136) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:276) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
... 22 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:402) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:318) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:136) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:276) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[?:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:356) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:318) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:136) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:276) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
... 22 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Error occurred while accessing Java Security Manager Privilege Block
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager.callSecure(JDBCAuthorizationManager.java:1530) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager.populatePermissionTreeFromDB(JDBCAuthorizationManager.java:1388) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager.(JDBCAuthorizationManager.java:175) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[?:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:356) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:318) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:136) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:276) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
... 22 more
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:573) ~[?:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager.callSecure(JDBCAuthorizationManager.java:1515) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager.populatePermissionTreeFromDB(JDBCAuthorizationManager.java:1388) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager.(JDBCAuthorizationManager.java:175) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[?:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:356) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:318) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:136) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:276) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager$2.run(JDBCAuthorizationManager.java:1518) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569) ~[?:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager.callSecure(JDBCAuthorizationManager.java:1515) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager.populatePermissionTreeFromDB(JDBCAuthorizationManager.java:1388) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager.(JDBCAuthorizationManager.java:175) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[?:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:356) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:318) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:136) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:276) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.contains(java.lang.CharSequence)" because "name" is null
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.TreeNode.modify(TreeNode.java:309) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.TreeNode.authorizeRole(TreeNode.java:151) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.PermissionTree.authorizeRoleInTree(PermissionTree.java:170) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.PermissionTree.updatePermissionTreeFromDB(PermissionTree.java:1140) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager.populatePermissionTreeFromDB(JDBCAuthorizationManager.java:1391) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager$2.run(JDBCAuthorizationManager.java:1518) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569) ~[?:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager.callSecure(JDBCAuthorizationManager.java:1515) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager.populatePermissionTreeFromDB(JDBCAuthorizationManager.java:1388) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager.(JDBCAuthorizationManager.java:175) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[?:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:356) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:318) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:136) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:276) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.8.1.7.jar:?]
... 22 more


There was an API that created an issue at the time of creation and while updating some configs this error came. However, After deletion of the API entry from apim_db DB from table am_api and um_permission in the shared_db, it gets back and works fine.

Thank you Noman.
My problem was resolved, and I noticed that it only occurs with MySQL, I believe it is something related to the encode or even some special character saved in the registry database.
